# Trouble using sandbox of symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm new to symfony and I am trying to run a simple command on the command line but I get an error message.

When I try to execute the command:

```
d:\new_xam\xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox_1_2\sf_sandbox>symfony propel:build-model "
```

I get the error:

> 'php.exe' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does a 'php.exe -v" works ? if not it's a windows path issue.

You can use full path or define path to php dir in env path

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common issue on Windows systems for people new to Symfony and/or PHP.  It seems to be an issue with the PHP path.  See here: [http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/44895/?srch=php.exe+command#msg_44895](http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/44895/?srch=php.exe+command#msg_4489)

Comment: ive tried to change the path , but the path is fine ,still its giving the same error 'php.exe' is not recognized
path set c:\program files\xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox\

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prefix everything with "php".

So instead of `symfony propel:build-model` you can do `php symfony propel:build-model`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the real path for PHP?

i.e.,

```
"C:\Program Files\PHP\PHP.exe" symfony propel:build-model
```

At your Symfony directory.